# Pre-booking vs booking?

Tags: verbs, nouns

I came across this work in my work,  I am not sure which one to use for a screen menu in our application, "pre-booking" or "booking". This menu will allow users to book their work schedule in advance. Is there any difference between the two ?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please show what your own research yields. What information does a dictionary give you about those words. Please have a look at the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about posting good questions.

Comment: Consider a similar construction: *pre-order* vs *order*. *Pre-book* should mean something like *place on a queue before the organisers are properly ready to accept bookings*, but in practice, *pre-book* is often used as a synonym for *book*, which already has the notion of *in advance*.

Comment: I've seen "pre-booking" used in a couple of ways.  One is where there is a normal period during which reservation can be made.  Pre-booking is used for reservations made before, and outside of, the normal process, often by special arrangements.  Another refers to something that is closer to "calling dibs" on a preference, or reserving a specific booking option, but isn't binding.

Answer (score 0):

**Pre-booking** specifically denotes that you have booked something in advance,

> Book (something) in advance:
>   *a pre-booked hotel reservation*
>   ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pre-book))

whilst **booking**

> Reserve accommodation for (someone):
>   *his secretary had booked him into the hotel*
>   ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/book#book__22))

merely connotes these meanings and booking would refer to the reservation more generally and not specifically the act of booking it beforehand

Comment: Can you add your sources, please.

Comment: @Helmar Editted

Comment: What do you mean by 'motto' here? Can you rephrase the last line?

Comment: @NVZ I'm not sure why the word 'motto' was in there, I can only think it was a typo